# gridview in a formtag which is in a content place holder tag doesnt accept

Tags: asp.net

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <asp:Content ID="content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
       <div>

        <asp:GridView ID="gvapproveweekend" runat="server" BackColor="#DEBA84" BorderColor="#DEBA84" BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="3" CellSpacing="2" OnRowCommand = "OnRowCommand">
            <Columns>
                <asp:ButtonField  ButtonType="Button" CommandName="Approve" Text="Approve"  />
                <asp:ButtonField  ButtonType="Button" CommandName="Reject" Text="Reject" />
            </Columns>

        </asp:GridView>
        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlData" runat="server"></asp:SqlDataSource>

        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>

    </div>
  </form>
</body>
</html>
      </asp:Content>
```

*I commented the Form tag and tried executing but getting this error
"Control 'head_gvapproveweekend' of type 'GridView' must be placed inside a form tag with runat=server. "*

If i keep the form for the sake og grid another error is thrown *"A page can have only one server-side Form tag. "*

Need a solution for this thanks in advance

Comment: i think you should learn more about  `Master Page` . Your `Master Page` already have a form tag, html head and body. You don't need those in content page once again.

Comment: Thanks the form tag was outside content place holder in master page